# Chrome crashes when opening >150 tabs. How to ensure stability with 150+ tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, crash, windows-error-reporting

I have been using Chrome for years awith approx 100 tabs. All good.
However at approx 150 tabs mark Chrome shows me this error often and becomes unstable, to the point that it has to be closed and reopened. Restoring all tabs allows for contiuation where I left off, however its not very stable this way.

My Windows 10 64 bit with 16GB of ram.
Isn't 16GB ram enough for 150 tabs in Chrome?
What must I do to not get this error AND continue using Chrome with 150+ tabls FAULTLESSLY?

[image]

Comment: Wow.. I usually feel a need to close tabs as soon as there is about 10 open. 100? I can't even imagine that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What Happened there?

Applications keep updating and Chrome keeps getting RAM hungry after every update. That's why after 100 tabs, Chrome would get Choppy as it had started using Virtual Memory as RAM cannot accommodate any more data and it crashes as it reaches 150 due to both **RAM Overflow** and **Page File Overflow**. Of course, the number of tabs may differ from session to sessions as some websites may use more resources than the others.

### Increasing Stability with a large number of tabs

We all know that Chrome is a power hungry application. Follow the below steps to increase your browser stability and experience.

1. The most obvious solution is to install more RAM in your system.
2. Running Chrome off a Solid State Disks (SSDs) would also help decrease IO times.
3. Increase your System Page File Size (Virtual Memory) by [following these instructions](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10,36929.html).
4. Tab suspenders like [The Great Supender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) add-on for Chrome automatically suspends or cache tabs in the background, freeing up the memory and CPU being consumed by that tab.
5. This may sound a bit weird but installing **lightweight** adblockers can help you disable unwanted ads/content and disable javascript on sites leading to lower resource usage. (Alternatively, you can also **disable Javascript** in settings)
6. Uninstall/Disable add-ons in Chrome since they always keep running in the background hoarding system resources
7. Close all unwanted programs in Windows to make sure Chrome can eat more RAM.

Answer (score 3):

0xC0000017 means a process couldn't start because there isn't enough free RAM.

Try increasing the size of your page file or installing more RAM.

Modern sites tend to use a lot of media assets and heavy Javascript libraries which might consume more RAM than you would think.

Comment: Upvoted Thanks very much, Wauw I never thought upgrading a 16GB memory machine would have any usefull benefits but it seems 32GB could be sometimes vaulable to avoid crashing (150+ tabs in) chrome alone!